# React Game Provider varibles isn't updated on logical function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have a GameEngine Provider who provide some data (here an example of boolean `isReady` but can also provide data from other hook like `usePlayer` or function to update state like `setText`)

Then on my code I have some logical function (like `initializeGame`) who receive the gameEngine object and is able to

- call function to update state, example `setText`
- retrieve value, example `isReady`

I tested following code and the `setText` is working fine, I displayed the `text` content on the HTML and it display well the `Loading...`

But retrieving the data isn't working, this is the log I receive (no text or isReady update):

#### Logs showing the issue

```
Is game ready:   false false 
Is game ready:   false false
SET Ready
Is game ready:   false false
Is game ready:   false false
Is game ready:   false false
```

### [CodePen reproduction](https://codepen.io/ArthyFiciel/pen/gOEEaRv)

#### Code example

```
import { Dispatch, PropsWithChildren, createContext, useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { PlayerContextType, usePlayer } from "./usePlayer";

export type GameEngineContextType = {
  isReady: boolean,
  getReady: () => boolean,

  text: string,
  setText: Dispatch<string>,

  updateGameStep: () => void,
  player: PlayerContextType,
}

export const GameEngineContext = createContext<GameEngineContextType | undefined>(undefined);
export const GameEngineProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren): JSX.Element => {

  // Engine States
  const isLoaded = useRef<boolean>(false);
  const [isReady, setReady] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState<string>("");

  // Example of other hook provided by GmeEngine
  const player = usePlayer();

  // Compose GameEngine
  const gameEngine: GameEngineContextType = {
    isReady,
    getReady: () => { return isReady },

    text, setText,

    updateGameStep: () => {  /* Go to the next game step */ },
    player,
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoaded.current) {
      isLoaded.current = true
      initializeGame(gameEngine);

      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("SET Ready")
        setReady(true)
      }, 2000)
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <GameEngineContext.Provider value={gameEngine}>
      {children}
    </GameEngineContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useGameEngine = () => {
  const context = useContext(GameEngineContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useGameEngine must be used inside GameEngineContext");
  }
  return context;
};

export function waitForCondition(
  conditionFn: () => boolean,
  intervalTime: number = 1000,
): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (conditionFn()) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        resolve(true);
      }
    }, intervalTime)
  })
}

export const initializeGame = async (gameEngine: GameEngineContextType) => {

  gameEngine.setText("Loading...");

  // Wait GameEngine to be ready
  await waitForCondition(() => {
    console.log("Is game ready: ", gameEngine.text, gameEngine.isReady, gameEngine.getReady());
    return gameEngine.isReady;
  });

  // Call function to go on the next step
  gameEngine.updateGameStep();
}
```

#### Render test

I also create an example of Components display data and it's working fine. I have

> Text: Loading... / Ready: No

Then after the Set Ready (2000 ms)

> Text: Loading... / Ready: Yes

```
function GameData() {
  const { text, isReady } = useGameEngine();
  return <>Text: {text} / Ready: {isReady ? "Yes" : "No"}</>
}

export default function Game() {
  return (
    <GameEngineProvider>
      <GameData />
    </GameEngineProvider>
  )
};
```

#### Test using a function

I also tested to used function `getReady`, so even if gameEngine object isn't updated the context where the function is created should ref to the right varaible, but not working neighter.

#### Test with object

I also update `isReady` to be an object `{value:boolean}` instead of `boolean` to see if object-ref is working, but still have `false` even after the update to `{value:true}`

#### Test with Ref

I also update `isReady` to be an ref with `useRef` instead of `boolean` to see if react ref are working, but still have `false` even after the update to `isReady.current = true`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `useRef` instead of useState.
`setReady(true);` cannot affect to waitForCondition's callback.
Because `isReady` type is boolean.

```
import React, { Dispatch, PropsWithChildren, createContext, useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "https://esm.sh/react@18";
import ReactDOM from "https://esm.sh/react-dom@18";


const GameData = () => {
  const { text, isReady } = useGameEngine();
  return <>Text: {text} / Ready: {isReady.value ? "Yes" : "No"}</>
};

const Game = () => {
  return (
    <GameEngineProvider>
      <GameData />
    </GameEngineProvider>
  )
};
const App = () => {
  return(
    <Game/>
  );
};

type GameEngineContextType = {
  isReady: boolean,
  getReady: () => boolean,

  text: string,
  setText: Dispatch<string>,

  updateGameStep: () => void,
}

const GameEngineContext = createContext<GameEngineContextType | undefined>(undefined);
const GameEngineProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren): JSX.Element => {

  // Engine States
  const isLoaded = useRef<boolean>(false);
  const [isReady, setReady] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const isReadyRef = useRef<boolean>(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState<string>("");


  // Compose GameEngine
  const gameEngine: GameEngineContextType = {
    isReady,
    getReady: () => isReadyRef.current,

    text, setText,

    updateGameStep: () => {  /* Go to the next game step */ },
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoaded.current) {
      isLoaded.current = true
      initializeGame(gameEngine);

      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("SET Ready")
        setReady(true);
        isReadyRef.current = true;
      }, 2000)
    }
  }, []);
    

  return (
    <GameEngineContext.Provider value={gameEngine}>
      {children}
    </GameEngineContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useGameEngine = () => {
  const context = useContext(GameEngineContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useGameEngine must be used inside GameEngineContext");
  }
  return context;
};

function waitForCondition(
  conditionFn: () => boolean,
  intervalTime: number = 1000,
): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (conditionFn()) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        resolve(true);
      }
    }, intervalTime)
  })
}

const initializeGame = async (gameEngine: GameEngineType) => {

  gameEngine.setText("Loading...");

  // Wait GameEngine to be ready
  await waitForCondition(() => {
    console.log("Is game ready: ", gameEngine.text, gameEngine.isReady, gameEngine.getReady());
    return gameEngine.getReady();
  });

  // Call function to go on the next step
  gameEngine.updateGameStep();
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />,
document.getElementById("root"))
```